# react-native eaxmple is not working

Tags: react-native

I tried react-native 'Button' example on React Native by O'REILLY.
But it's not working correctly.
When click the button, it isn't change to 'EEK!'
It is still 'PUSH ME'.
Are there something wrong?
I added my code...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

class test extends Component {
  // this is constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pressing: false };
  }

  _onPressIn = () => {
    this.setState({pressing: true});
  }

  _onPressOut = () => {
    this.setState({pressing: false});
  }

  //  {this.state.pressing ? 'EEK!' : 'PUSH ME'} not working
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPressIn={this._onPressIn}
          onPressOut={this._onPressOut}
          style={styles.touchable}>

          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.welcome}>
              {this.state.pressing ? 'EEK!' : 'PUSH ME'}
            </Text>
          </View>

        </TouchableHighlight>

        <Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
                style={{width: 400, height: 400, resizeMode: 'contain'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome : {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  touchable: {
    borderRadius: 100
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
    borderRadius: 100,
    height: 200,
    width: 200,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  italic: {
    fontStyle: "italic"
  }
});

class Strong extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.bold}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

class Em extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={styles.italic}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}

export default test;
```

Comment: sorry, it works. not short click but long click

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, you have to use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` instead of `TouchableHighlight`. There are no such props as `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` on `TouchableHighlight`, it does exist on `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. Here are the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html) explaining it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
{this.state.pressing ? 'EEK!' : 'PUSH ME'}
```

Try to write

```
{this.state.text}
```

And put the text in state (don't forgot the , between pressing and text) :

```
text:'EEK!'
```

And in on pressing and out pressing, update the text just like you've done with pressing !

It should work =)